# Iterate through a group of elements with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a website in WordPress where I need to edit many pages.
Here is list of them:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtiuo.png)

I need iterate through every this page: `'apple'` '`banana'` etc
to click it and make some edition.
However don't know how to do it because id's differ a lot when I tried to do it by Xpath:

```
apple - //*[@id="post-11515"]/td[1]/strong/a
banana - //*[@id="post-11501"]/td[1]/strong/a
```

and this is how html of a single 'a href' looks like:

```
<a class="row-title" href="https://address.pl/wp-admin/post.php?post=11216&amp;action=edit"aria-label="„apple” (Edycja)">apple</a>
```

Do you have any idea how i can make a loop to iterate through those items?

Answer (score 1):

You can store all the `a` tag elements and then iterate in a for loop. Like-

```
    options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".../a")
    ''' Can also use driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a") 
        if they are only elements in a tag '''
    for opt in options:
           #code to make changes
           driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

See these two id's for Apple and Banana : -

```
apple - //*[@id="post-11515"]/td[1]/strong/a
banana - //*[@id="post-11501"]/td[1]/strong/a
```

you can construct a xpath to represent all of them, and then can do indexing to iterate through :-

**xpath**

```
//*[contains(@id, 'post')]/td[1]/strong/a
```

and click it like this :

```
import time
for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id, 'post')]/td[1]/strong/a"):
    item.click()
    time.sleep(.5)
```